# TYPO3 - BUG There is no entry in the $TCA array

Tags: typo3, typo3-4.5

I have a bug in my TYPO3 4.5 website :

> Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: #1283790586:
>   There is no entry in the $TCA array for the table
>   "pages_language_overlay". This means that the function enableFields()
>   is called with an invalid table name as argument. |
>   InvalidArgumentException thrown in file /t3lib/class.t3lib_page.php in
>   line 1150

I don't understand what happens, but my backend is still available.
How to fix it ?

Comment: I wouldn't expect many answers here since TYPO3 4.5 is ancient. You should relaunch your project with TYPO3 8.7 or at least upgrade to that version.

Comment: Hi, I know and am currently working on a migration plan but for the moment I need to fix this issue :) I hope someone would help me anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you do not know much about TYPO3 so I try to make clear how TYPO3 is working (with regards to the old version).

TYPO3 has definitions of the tables and fields in the database.
First part are the MySQL definitions (since 8 it might be other databases than MySQL).
The second part (TCA = **T**YPO3 **C**onfiguration **A**rray) are the definitions how these tables build the BackEnd(BE) Interface for an editor.

As these informations can be enhanced by extensions, each extension can add it's information to a (cached) pool and this pool is considered a reference.

The database definitions are located in files **`ext_tables.sql`**. The TCA **was** generated in **`ext_localconf.php`** and **`ext_tables.php`**. Today TCA modifications should be done in `Configuration/TCA/`*`tablename`*`.php` (for new tables) or `Configuration/TCA/Override/`*`tablename`*`.php` (for modification of existing tables).

Before all these files are included and executed for every call they are collected and stored as one resulting PHP-file.

Your problem might occur because there is a syntax error in the collected file and up to the error all information is build up, but everything after the error is missing.
Try to clean up your installation and remove these caches: in pre 6 versions there are files `temp_CACHED_<hash>_ext_tables.php` and `temp_CACHED_<hash>_ext_localconf.php` in your `typo3conf/` folder. Remove them all. The next call to TYPO3 (FE or BE) will rebuild two files. Make sure these have no syntax errors.

In the install-tool (`<domain>/typo3/install/`) you can clear all caches and compare the existing database with the gathered definition from all active(!) extensions. If there are differences the database can be *'corrected'*. **Be sure to have a database backup before you change anything.**

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Actually this post is more than 1 year old. I ran into the same error when I upgraded from 7.6 to 8.7. I'm also a newbie in `typo3`. How can I find out, if there is a syntax error and if so, where it is? Maybe you have a hint for me?

Answer (score 0):

The usal answer: TYPO3 4.5 is outdated. Upgarade your installation to a newer version. Maybe the Bug is allready solved.

If an Update is not possible then the question is what you have doing that the error is thrown. What changes were done at latest? What extension was shortly installed or updated?

Comment: Hello, I know it's outdated but my client website is still on V4.5 for the moment. According to the logs, a user made an update on a tt_news, then cleared the cache and BIM ! Error message. I don't understand ?

Comment: Maybe the cache was not updated corretly, clear the cache again. Try also to delete the cache manualy by deleting the `typo3conf/temp_*` files.

Comment: It works now, i made a "Clear All caches". Anyway I worry about this bug because it would happens anytime and if i'm not here to fix it.... Why wasn't the cache well cleared ? What's the point with this table "pages_language_overlay" and how to prevent more problems ?

Comment: That can i not say, maybe the connection was interupted or an bug caused this. Thats why my first answer was to upgrade the installation. Many bugs are fixed.